# Weird Black Hole definition

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, definition

I'm quite new to the topic of Black Holes, and I can't understand the definition (given in [Wald, R.M. (2005). The Thermodynamics of Black Holes. In: Gomberoff, A., Marolf, D. (eds) Lectures on Quantum Gravity. Series of the Centro De Estudios Científicos. Springer, Boston, MA. https://doi.org/10.1007/0-387-24992-3_1](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/0-387-24992-3_1)):

$$B = M-I^-(I^+),$$

where $M$ defines an asymptotically flat spacetime $(M,g_{\alpha\beta})$ (representing an isolated system), $I^+$ denotes future null infinity (what's that?) and $I^-$ the chronological past. I don't understand the notations and the definitions. Please help.

Comment: Please add references.

Comment: [Series of the Centro de Estudios Cientificos 1571-571X] Andres Gomberoff, Donald Marolf - Lectures on Quantum Gravity (2005, Springer)